# Efficient sorted diff in dask

Tags: python, dataframe, sorting, dask

How can I do the following in Dask in an "efficient" way:

My dask dataframe has columns 'Date' (datetime), 'MAC' (category), and 'ID' (int) which is already sorted by date, and I want to get a new column with the timedeltas for the arrival of http requests for a given mac address.

In pandas I would have done the following: setup a multi-index ['ID', 'MAC'] and then build a new column 'Timedelta' with a `df['Date'].diff(1)`. It seems multi-index is not supported so the same solution can't be reproduced. The important part is that diffs must be done for a same MAC, between a given request, and the following that was recorder (so sorted by date).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might be able to do this with a groupby-apply?  This will induce a shuffle (which is somewhat slow), but should get the job done.

```
df.groupby('MAC').apply(lambda df: df.assign(diff=df.Date.diff(1))
```

I haven't actually done this though, so I expect this will need tweaking.

Comment: This answer works, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to define metadata for this solution. Do you have any suggestions?